# Insert Records Into Multiple Tables Using Forms Access 2010

Tags: ms-access

Okay guys I have a database I have been working on for days now. I have a `PartsInvPurTbl` where I insert data to be purchased and `PartsHisTbl` where the primary from the `PartsInvPurTbl` needs to be inserted into the the `PartsHisTbl`. I also have one additional table that I need to add more data from the `PartsInvPurTbl`. I believe that if I can get one to work I won't have a problem doing the others.

The thing here is that I have form that I use to insert the data fields. So there is an parts purchase Id field which is the primary key used for the parts history table.

My question is how do I get this to make a new record in the `PartsInvPurTbl` and a new record in the `PartsHisTbl`.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best option you have for this is to use VBA to write you multiple insert statements.

Comment: That would definately do the job for me and I can do this but since this is a class project I don't think the instructor is wanting this type of implementation.